# Circular page loading with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a page that displays a list of items, each item has a delete link next to it. When user clicks that link a delete confirmation page is loaded. If user clicks "No", the list page is loaded. Other things are not relevant to this question.

This works well in PHP, but now I'm trying to load everything with AJAX using jQuery. I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[class="link-delete"]').click(function(e){

    $.get(e.target.href, function(data){
      $('#main').html(data);  //loads the delete confirmation page

      $('#delete-button').click(function(e_delete){
        //User clicked "Yes", not relevant here
      });

      $('#cancel-button').click(function(e_cancel){
        e_cancel.preventDefault();
        $.get(e_cancel.target.href, function(data){
          $('#main').html(data); //loads the list page, that is starting page
          //I think I'm getting stuck here
        });
      });

    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

So, when user clicks a Delete link from the list, a call is made to PHP back-end and the part of the page is loaded asycnhronously and displayed properly. So far so good. Then, when a user clicks "No" (cancel button), the list is loaded through AJAX and displayed. However, when a user clicks a delete link now, jQuery is not executed. It works only after a refresh. I believe I'm getting "stuck" where I indicated in the code.

I don't even know the proper terminology here, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. I would like to load a page and still be able to capture events with the same jQuery code. Is this even possible with jQuery and how to do it? Could I use .load() with callback and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('body').on('click','a[class="link-delete"]',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    $.get(e.target.href, function(data){
      $('#main').html(data);  //loads the delete confirmation page
    });
 });
$('body').on('click','#delete-button',function(e){
  //User clicked "Yes", not relevant here
});

 $('body').on('click','#cancel-button',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(e.target.href, function(data){
       $('#main').html(data); //loads the list page, that is starting page
          //I think I'm getting stuck here
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it's because those `a[class="link-delete"]` elements that are loaded via Ajax don't have the event handler attached to them. They were created after your page loaded.

You need to look into event delegation (http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Assign the event listener to an element that *contains* those links and that will still be there after your document is updated via xhr.

Something like

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[class="link-delete"]', function(e) {
    // your event handler
});
```

should do the trick.